# Why does std::get not have a single signature that accepts a forwarding reference

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, stdtuple

Why does `std::get` for `std::tuple` have so many overloads (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)?  One corresponding to every possible combination of `const` `&` and `&&`?  With each combination the const ref qualifiers on the return value is the same.  Why not have just one single overload that accepts the tuple type by forwarding reference and then simply forward the return value based on the signature of the input?  Something like so

```
template <int Index, typename TupleType>
decltype(auto) get(TupleType&& tup);
```

This sort of thing would make it really easy for people to reason about what the `get` function does and would avoid bugs like Issue 2485 (https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2485)

Answer (score 4):

`std::get` existed prior to `decltype(auto)`.  So that was easy.

Ok, why not change it?

The body of `std::get` is not specified by the standard, and should not be as different compilers have different layouts and implementations of tuples.

`decltype(auto)` does not tell the reader of the standard, the user or implementor of a compiler, what the return type is.  It just says it is deduced from the body.  Which the standard does not specify.

It being in the standard like that would thus be useless, unless they described what the return value was separately, which in the  end would look a lot like listing overloads.

Comment: It should be noted that implementations are free to use `decltype(auto)` and just a single overload.

Comment: @Yakk does this imply that in a similar scenario it is a bad design decision to use `decltype(auto`) when the return value can either be an rvalue or an lvalue based on type deductions?  Should I have 4 overloads as well?

Comment: @curious are you a standards committee documenting interfaces but not implementation for millions of programmers and compiler writers?  If yes, then it is a bad idea.  If no, then my answer does not cover your case, and your situation is not "similar" enough.  If you have a completely different question you need answered, check that it is suitable to post on stackoverflow, and if so press the "ask a question" button and write it up.  I am not going to list the pros and cons in a comment thread.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of `std::get` cannot be deduced, because `std::get` is defined for many different types. (Ex. `tuple`, `pair`, `array`, `variant`).

For this reason more than any other `std::get` cannot deduce its parameter type. Changing it to deduction at this point would break real-world code, such as types deduced from tuple. For example the suggested signature change would yield a signature like:

`template <class TupleLike, class = enable_if_t<IsStdTuple<TupleLike>::value>>>
decltype(auto) get(TupleLike&&);`

This signature does not allow implicit conversions to the tuple type in the interface, like the older signatures did. As mentioned this breaks types which derive from `std::tuple` or types that have a conversion operator to `std::tuple`.

Libc++ implements the `tuple`, `pair` and `array` converting constructors using a single generic `TupleLike` overload. As the maintainer I'm intimately familiar with these implementation issues, and if I could implement a conforming `std::get` as you propose I already would.

Comment: I don't think types with a conversion function to `tuple` work anyway. Types derived from `tuple`, though, are supposed to work.

Comment: Could you use a combination of template template parameters and `std::is_convertible` to check if the argument can be converted to a tuple, or more generally to the template template parameter?

Comment: @Curious You can't use `is_convertible` because you don't know what specialization of `tuple` to check.

@T.C Types with a conversion operator to tuple should work, but there is a lot of implementation divergence in compiler frontends.

Comment: @EricWF You sure? Last time I checked, template argument deduction doesn't look through user-defined conversions.